# How to read comment from .cpp file and display it into text box?

Tags: c#, wpf

For example below, how to write the code to read the comment and to display it into a text box. /* and */ is blocked comments that can span multiple lines

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you want to remove all the `/` and `*` characters? There are several ways to do it, but a simple approach is replacing all the characters with an empty space and then trimming all the space later, here's a sample code to start you with:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string text = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"C:\test.cpp");
    text = text.Replace('/', ' ');
    text = text.Replace('*', ' ');

    //Do all possible cleaning of text: text.Trim() etc...

    //Put text into text box (for now just display into console)
    Console.WriteLine(text);
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

When you run the program make sure the `test.cpp` exists in your `C:\` drive.

If you are just removing the `/******/` beneath it, you can do the following instead:

```
string text = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"C:\test.cpp");
string[] lines = text.Split(new string[] { System.Environment.NewLine },
    StringSplitOptions.None);

//Gain control with each lines process as you wish, use StringBuilder etc.
for (int i = 0; i < lines.Length; i++ )
{
    Console.WriteLine(lines[i]);
}
Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: I need to display from /* to */, the whole comment actually.

Comment: You can use the second sample instead. It is splitted into several lines where you can choose which text you would like to display.

Answer (score 0):

The way I always do this, as you can spare yourself the stuff with the FileReading, just build the string you need somehow like this:

```
string text = 
    "Name       : John Ding\n" +
    "Project    : NTI\n" +
    "File       : AX0003.cpp\n" +
    "Description: Sample";
```

The Code from above will look like this now:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string text = 
        "Name       : John Ding\n" +
        "Project    : NTI\n" +
        "File       : AX0003.cpp\n" +
        "Description: Sample";

    //Put text into text box (for now just display into console)
    Console.WriteLine(text);
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

This would be the approach if your Description is static. If otherwise, I recommend above solution, too. This one here is just less likely to throw an error as you do not have to handle things like a FileNotFoundException.